# ListCellRenderer casting exception

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listcellrenderer

Here is the code of the custom renderer:

```
private class FacilityElement extends javax.swing.JLabel implements javax.swing.ListCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        if(isSelected) {
            setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
            setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
        }
        else {
            setBackground(list.getBackground());
            setForeground(list.getForeground());
        }
        setFont(list.getFont());
        setText(" " + ((Facility) value).getName()); // The error is here
        setOpaque(true);

        return this;
    }

}
```

Everything works fine except when there are no items in the `DefaultComboBoxModel`, in which case `getListCellRendererComponent` is called with `String` value of `""`, which causes the error as it expects a `Facility` object instead.

Why does it behave this way?

**Update**: I know that the error is because of the casting and I know how to use `instance of`, the question is why it behaves this way (the function), if there are no elements, I would expect it not to be called at all, but why it is called? After all, what does it format if there are no elements.

**Update**: The accepted answer below can be used. As for why it behaves so, it is because the list has to have an empty string; you know the empty string that is selected by default when initializing the combobox for the first time.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Always copy/paste error & exception output.

Comment: downcasting is dangereous , use `instanceof`

Comment: never to set value to the rendering component inside XxxRenderer

Comment: check the code that fills/adds items to the model: verify that all of them are of type Facility and not null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private class FacilityElement extends javax.swing.JLabel implements javax.swing.ListCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        if(isSelected) {
            setBackground(list.getSelectionBackground());
            setForeground(list.getSelectionForeground());
        }
        else {
            setBackground(list.getBackground());
            setForeground(list.getForeground());
        }
        setFont(list.getFont());
        if (value instanceof Facility) { // Try this
            setText(" " + ((Facility) value).getName()); 
        }    
        setOpaque(true);

        return this;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.